# Obtener el nombre de un directorio con GetDirectories

Tags: c#

Logro que me devuelta la ruta completa al hacer el listado, pero únicamente quiero el nombre del último directorio que es lo que me interesa:

```
Directorios.Items.Clear();

            // CREAMOS LA OPCIÓN RAIZ
            Directorios.Items.Add("...");

            try
            {
                string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(carpeta);
                
                foreach (string dir in dirs)
                {
                    Directorios.Items.Add(dir);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("No se ha podido acceder al Directorio Raíz", "Error de Sistema");
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes separar la última parte del directorio y quedarte solo con esta.

```cs
try
{
    string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(carpeta);
                
    foreach (string dir in dirs)
    {
        string ultimaParte = dir.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Last();
        Directorios.Items.Add(ultimaParte);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("No se ha podido acceder al Directorio Raíz", "Error de Sistema");
}
```

La constante `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` representa el separador de directorios del sistema donde se está ejecutando el programa, con lo que en Windows usará `\` y en sistemas tipo Unix usará `/`. Con Last() obtienes el último elemento (una string), que es lo que guardas.

Comment: Me devuelve lo mismo

Comment: @JesúsPrieto prueba el código que puse ahora. Tienes que añadir  `ultimaParte` a Directorios, no añadir `dir`. Fue un error por mi parte, disculpa.

Comment: Ahora si, lo que pasa es que este código no me deja usar el SelectedValue luego para seleccionar la opción correcta.

Comment: @JesúsPrieto ¿qué SelectedValue? Eso no lo vi en la pregunta por ningún sitio